# How does `pd.date_range()` creates an object of `DatetimeIndex`, without calling any method of the class `DatetimeIndex`?

Tags: python, pandas, date-range, datetimeindex

This is the csv file I am using, which has day column as index

```
            temperature  windspeed   event
day                                       
2017-01-01         32.0        6.0    Rain
2017-01-04          NaN        9.0   Sunny
2017-01-05         28.0        NaN    Snow
2017-01-06          NaN        7.0     NaN
2017-01-07         32.0        NaN    Rain
2017-01-08          NaN        NaN   Sunny
2017-01-09          NaN        NaN     NaN
2017-01-10         34.0        8.0  Cloudy
2017-01-11         40.0       12.0   Sunny
```

I am running this code to insert missing date values in the day column which contains the date values.

```
dt = pd.date_range("01-01-2017","01-11-2017")
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(dt)
df = df.reindex(idx)
```

The code is working fine but I want to understand how does this code snippet works behind the scene so I looked into documentation but couldn't find the exact explanation.

Then I asked ChatGPT, it says that the `pd.date_range()` creates an instance of the class DatetimeIndex. So I asked it, which method of the DatetimeIndex class is called when `pd.date_range()` function is used?

It answered that, `pd.date_range()` doesn't directly call the constructor of the DatetimeIndex class, but it accomplishes the same result.

I am not able to understand this. Can someone please explain me this?

Comment: This is what happens when you rely on AI for understanding.  You get misunderstanding.

Comment: Can you please explain this? @MarkRansom

Comment: How do you know that what ChatGPT told you is true?  You can't.  I believe the answer is wrong, you can't create an object in Python without calling the class `__init__` method.  Wrong answers lead to misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to explicitly call `DatetimeIndex`, [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) already returns a `DatetimeIndex`.

```
# ensure index is datetime
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

dt = pd.date_range("01-01-2017","01-11-2017")
out = df.reindex(dt)
```

Why? Because it was written to do so:

> **pandas.date_range** pandas.date_range(start=None, end=None, periods=None, freq=None, tz=None, normalize=False, name=None,
> inclusive='both', *, unit=None, **kwargs)
>
> ...
>
> Returns:
> DatetimeIndex

Output:

```
            temperature  windspeed   event
2017-01-01         32.0        6.0    Rain
2017-01-02          NaN        NaN     NaN
2017-01-03          NaN        NaN     NaN
2017-01-04          NaN        9.0   Sunny
2017-01-05         28.0        NaN    Snow
2017-01-06          NaN        7.0     NaN
2017-01-07         32.0        NaN    Rain
2017-01-08          NaN        NaN   Sunny
2017-01-09          NaN        NaN     NaN
2017-01-10         34.0        8.0  Cloudy
2017-01-11         40.0       12.0   Sunny
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I thought the same but I was not sure because I was learning this by watching a YouTube video and in that he writes the code this way

Comment: @IRONMAN I'd recommend to forget about ChatGPT to learn how to code (it's very bad, even when it gives code that seems to work). And to always refer to the official python/pandas documentation, which are well written.

Comment: Thank you @mozway, I will keep that in mind. I still have one question. Which method does the `pd.date_range()` function calls to create an object of the class `DatetimeIndex`. I looked in the documentation about this but couldn't find. Can you please explain me?

Comment: Have you checked the [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.1/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py#L822-L1020)? It calls one `DatetimeIndex` method (`_simple_new`) directly. But why are you asking all this?